# Jquery on ipad doesn't work

Tags: jquery

This code:

```
$('#x').hide();
$('#y').hide();
alert($('#y').is(":visible"));
alert($('#x').is(":visible"));
```

when on ipad, shows two alerts which say true. How is this possible? On Chrome they show false, as they are supposed to.

Comment: what results do you get if you try `alert($('#y').is(':hidden'));` ?

Comment: if the `:hidden` and `:visible` selectors aren't reliable, you may have to test the `.css('display')` value or check for `.height() > 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the callback parameter :

```
$('#x').hide(0, function() {
    alert($('#y').is(":visible"));
});
```

The function will be executed only when the animation is finished.
Though, this is supposed to be done without any animation...

Answer (score 1):

I think jQuery does not wait for animations to be finished before the next code is interpreted. Maybe the IPad is faster interpreting than hiding and therefore both elements are still visible.

You can check this by using `window.setTimeout`

Comment: IIRC, `hide()` sets the css value of display to none immediately. Could be wrong, it's been a while since I've needed to know that :)

Comment: No, you're right, `hide()` is not a real animation. Still I thought, there might be a time issue...

Comment: yeah according to the docs you *can* specify a duration and a callback. although it doesnt say so explicitly, I *think* it defaults to 0. http://api.jquery.com/hide/